# Changing the width of a Checkbox in css

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

Set the width of the checkbox for the call field to 25 pixels, displayed only when the left margin is clear.

Not sure why I can't figure this out, it's probably something simple, again. I made sure my stylesheets and everything match up this time.

here's the html code for the item:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="call" id="call"></p>
<p><label for="call">Please contact me for a "Get to Know You" visit.</label></p>
```

and here is the CSS i'm trying to use:

```
.checkbox {
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 25px; }
```

[This is what the form is suppose to look like (don't mind the submit and cancel buttons, havent got there yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQHAq.png)

[Here is what mine looks like with the current CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1TiG.png)

Is there a specific selector for just the physical checkbox? and why is it all the way up in the corner of the form?

//-UPDATE-//
I added the class="checkbox" to the input attribute, and the checkbox moved to the correct spot.

Now the Label "Please contact me for a "Get to Know You" visit." Will not align properly. It is suppose to have the width directly after the checkbox set to auto and the value of the clear property is none. I have tried everything I can think of, but I can't get it to line up. What selector should I be using?

Comment: off topic but I hope those details are not real in the images.

Comment: where have you defined class in the input? add class='checkbox'

Comment: you want to change the width or the size of the checkbox?

Comment: Lol i don't think they are, it was just examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more detail as to what you mean about the width of the checkbox. but in terms of the css applying to the checkbox, you either need to specify a class on your input or restrict the css to the input[type=checkbox]

```css
.checkbox {
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 25px; }

input[type=checkbox] {
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 25px; }
```

```html
<p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="call" id="call"></p>
<p><label for="call">Please contact me for a "Get to Know You" visit.</label></p>
  
<hr/>

<p><input type="checkbox" name="call" id="call"></p>
<p><label for="call">Please contact me for a "Get to Know You" visit.</label></p>
```

Comment: I wish I could, those are the exact instructions I was given.

Comment: I was hoping someone else knew what the question meant.

Comment: Well the class selector worked, its in the right place, idk if its a different size, but I think that's what I needed. Thank you Nathan :)